# Splitting a dataframe on delimiter 4th from right

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split

Is there a way to split a dataframe on the 4th delimiter from the right?

For example, if I wanted to split this:

```
A
Hello, world, what can, I do for, you
Hi, Hi, Hi, Hi, Hi, Hi
Yes, Yes, Heloo, Hi, Hi, Hi, Hi
```

Into this:

```
A                                        B                      C
Hello, world, what can, I do for, you    Hello                  world, what can, I do for, you
Hi, Hi, Hi, Hi, Hi, Hi                   Hi, Hi                 Hi, Hi, Hi, Hi
Yes, Yes, Heloo, Hi, Hi, Hi, Hi          Yes, Yes, Heloo        Hi, Hi, Hi, Hi
```

I know that I can use the following to split on the last delimiter.

```
NEWDF = DF.A.str.rsplit(', ', 1, expand=True).rename(lambda x: f'col{x + 1}', axis=1)
```

I am just wondering if there is a way to split on the x from last...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, it should work.

```
delimiter = ', '
A = 'Hello, world, what can, I do for, you'
splitted = A.split(delimiter)
B = delimiter.join(splitted[:-4])
C = delimiter.join(splitted[-4:])
```